# What and How to set up "App Pricing" when uploading app in Google Play

Tags: google-play

I'm new to Android and Google Play. Now I upload a new app here but I don't understand about **App Pricing** section.

My app has in-app purchase for coin to unlock more level with plans are: 1 USD = 100 coins. 10 USD = 1000 coins.

So what should I config this **App Pricing** section? And what's the **Pricing templates**?

Thank you very much!